# How to list all enabled network connection names (Interfaces)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I use the following Delphi procedure `GetAdapters` to list all enabled network adapters:

```
procedure GetAdapters;
var
  oBindObj : IDispatch;
  oNetAdapters, oNetAdapter,
  odnsAddr, oWMIService : OleVariant;
  i, iValue : LongWord;
  oEnum : IEnumVariant;
  oCtx : IBindCtx;
  oMk : IMoniker;
  sFileObj : WideString;
begin
  MainForm.sComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  sFileObj := 'winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2';

  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0,oCtx));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayNameEx(oCtx, PWideChar(sFileObj), i, oMk));
  OleCheck(oMk.BindToObject(oCtx, nil, IUnknown, oBindObj));
  oWMIService := oBindObj;

  oNetAdapters := oWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE PhysicalAdapter=True AND MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND AdapterType IS NOT NULL');

  oEnum := IUnknown(oNetAdapters._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;

  while oEnum.Next(1, oNetAdapter, iValue) = 0 do begin
    try
      MainForm.sCombobox1.Items.Add(oNetAdapter.Caption);
    except
    end;

    oNetAdapter := Unassigned;
  end;

  odnsAddr := Unassigned;
  oNetAdapters := Unassigned;
  oWMIService := Unassigned;
end;
```

When I need to change my IP, I need to specify the network interface name, not the adapter name.

How can I list the network connection names like it is listed in Windows Network and Sharing Center.

Example:

Windows 7

```
Local Area Connection
Wireless Network Connection
Wireless Network Connection 1
```

Windows 10

```
Wifi
Wifi 2
etc..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216.aspx) has an `InterfaceIndex` property.  Read an adapter's `InterfaceIndex` value and then run another query searching [`Win32_IP4RouteTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394162.aspx) for the same `InterfaceIndex` value.  `Win32_IP4RouteTable` has `Name`, `Caption`, and `Description` properties.

That being said, `Win32_NetworkAdapter` is deprecated, mainly because it only supports IPv4.  Use [`MSFT_NetAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968170.aspx) instead, which supports both IP4 and IPv6, and has `InterfaceName` and `InterfaceDescription` properties.

That being said, an alternative option is not to use WMI for this task.  You can use [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) instead.  It returns an array of `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` items, where `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` has `IfIndex` and `Ipv6IfIndex` fields, which can be used to match up entries in the arrays returned by [`GetInterfaceInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365947.aspx), [`GetIfTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943.aspx), [`GetIfTable2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365945.aspx), etc.

Comment: in fact i don't know how to use the other functions you told,  i'm new to networking, if you can give me an example code, for now i fixed it by change    MainForm.sCombobox1.Items.Add(oNetAdapter.Caption); to     MainForm.sCombobox1.Items.Add(oNetAdapter.NetConnectionID);  thanks for your detailed answer, i will keep searching and learning